# how to pull the data from database to combo box

Tags: sql, vb.net

i am trying to pull the data from database to combo box , i have 2 combo box and i want to display data from different tables. 
this is the code i was trying.

```
Try
        'declare variables

        Dim objDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim objDataAdapter1 As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim objDataSet As New DataSet()
        Dim objDataSet1 As New DataSet()

        '//state dataset of combo box
        ' Set the SelectCommand properties...
        objDataAdapter.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand()
        objDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Connection = sql.SqlConn
        objDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "select * from tblBrand"
        objDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        '//mention the second data 
        objdataadapter1.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand()
        objDataAdapter1.SelectCommand.Connection = sql.SqlConn
        objDataAdapter1.SelectCommand.CommandText = "select * from tblModel"
        objDataAdapter1.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        ' Open the database connection...
        sql.SqlConn.Open()
        ' Fill the DataSet object with data...
        objDataAdapter.Fill(objDataSet, "tblBrand")
        objDataAdapter1.Fill(objDataSet1, "tblModel")
        ' Close the database connection...
        sql.SqlConn.Close()

        With (cboxBrandName)
            .DataSource = objDataSet
            .ValueMember = "tblBrand.BandID"
            .DisplayMember = "tblBrand.BrandName"
        End With
        With (cboxModel)
            .DataSource = objDataSet1
            .ValueMember = "tblModel.ModelID"
            .DisplayMember = "tblModel.ModelName"
        End With

    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

in this line not showing any error but i cannot find any result in combo box.

Comment: nobody help me there , i am sorry if i did any wrong. i guess you too see that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I do it -

```
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(yourconnectionString)

    Const qry As String = "SELECT * FROM tblModel"

    conn.Open()
    Using da As New SqlDataAdapter(qry, conn)
        da.Fill(ds)
    End Using
    ' For Combobox

    With YourComboBoxName
        .DisplayMember = "what you want to display to the user in combobox"
        .ValueMember = "ID associated with each record"
        .DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        .SelectedIndex = 0
    End With

    conn.Close()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: True it helps me, can u give me onething, why you use this line here ".selectedindex=0 " ?

Comment: So if you want to change what the 'default' value shows up in the combobox you can add the selected index and it will show that display member associated with that Index.

Comment: in this case my index is 1 , brandid , brandname .... like this my table going. and my display member is brandname , brandid is the value member. so why we right selectedintex=0 , just am try to know the code .

Comment: You can make selectedindex whatever number you want if it's in the scope of the data, otherwise you'll get an `ArgumentOutOfRange` Exception

Comment: Thanks, i will try to do different project so i will understand , whats the real point. but now i know what is it. thanks newbie...